# Cakephp 3 asset link in a plugin with vendor namespace at top level

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to link the asset files of my sub plugin (plugin with a vendor namespace at top level) but it doesn't work properly. If I remove it and create a level above it, the file is normally found.
Template:

```
<?php
//Code in Template file (plugins/Comunica/Settings/src/Template/Settings/index.ctp)
$this->Html->script('Comunica/Settings.settings', ['block' => true]);
```

Javascript file:

```
//plugins/Comunica/Settings/webroot/js/settings.js
console.log('testing');
```

Generated Uri: /comunica/settings/settings.js

Is this a bug in the cake or am I baking by the wrong way?

Comment: What's the URL that is being generated?

Comment: It is "/comunica/settings/settings.js"